# Hibernate XML Mapping in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

Edit: I want to change the question a little :-)

I want to save a SaveGame Objet in a SQL database with Hibernate XML. All i want to is to save it. My problem is taht i cant find a way how to do it. I searched now for 3 hours on the internet and didnot find a solution.

All i want to do is to save a integer array as a normal value into my database. I found during my search i can do this with a blob column. But nowhere on this great internet i found the way how to do it. I simply search for a person that can show me how to do it right. Becasue all my tried failed. And i am frustrated now.

My Class that i want to save looks like this:

```
    public class SaveGame implements IDBObject {
    int id;
    String username;
    int basic_game_id;
    List<Integer> route = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   /*getter + setter */
```

The SaveGame table should look like this:

ID | username | basic_game_id | route |

1  | Maxi     |      1        | xxxxx |

I hope this time its clear what i want to do. I dont have to save every single array entry. I just want to save the whole array in the route column. And i cant find out how i can do this!

---

Old Question:

I try to map a Integer Array to my database with Hibernate.

This is how my Class looks

```
public class SaveGame implements IDBObject {
    int id;
    String username;
    int basic_game_id;
    List<Integer> route = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   /*getter + setter */
```

My mapping xml looks like this:

```
<class name="com.travelsales.base_classes.SaveGame" table="SAVEGAME">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the Save games.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="basic_game_id" type="int" column="basic_game_id"></property>
    <property name="username" type="string" column="username"></property>
    <list name="route" column="route">
        <element type="int"></element>
    </list>
</class>
```

Well i cant find the mistake.

My problem is that i must have an error in the xml mapping part. If i delete the list everything works fine. I want to save integer array or integer list in my database. And i think i have a mistake in the way i do it.

With this code i get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.travelsales.controller.MainController.main(MainController.java:42)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Hibernate Config/mapping.hbm.xml`

Comment: "Well i cant find the mistake." What mistake are you talking about?

Comment: Please do not use **Code snippet** for the type of code above. You just need to use the **Code Sample**. The snippet is used to run actual code. It is a little confusing.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please provide the error messages in your question.

Comment: This seems wrong: `<list name="route" column="route"><element type="int"></element></list>`, as it is an `Integer`list

Comment: if you're using Hibernate 3+, u can use annotations as well. Refer to this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples)

Comment: if u're looking only for xml, try this [one](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/persist-object-with-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, do you want to the route to be stored in separate table (to be searchable, etc) or are you happy to have it in same row as your SaveGame.

If your case is really as simple as you presented I would recommend storing in in the same row to save on fetching the int values from the join.

Map the property to a blob column and all is done. I am not using the xml configuration so dont know the syntax but with JPA annotations it is solved by the code:

```
@Lob
List<Integer> route;
```

If your hibernate version do not handle interfaces (you will get error messages), change the property declaration form List to ArrayList (which is serializable, so it can be saved as bytes in the blob column).

Comment: The error message mentions not being able to parse `mapping.hbm.xml`

Comment: I just want to save the route in SaveGame. The route is holding the id of sprites. (sprite is a table in my database with x and y coords.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, After all my trys and after all my study from online Documents. Maybe one day another person will have the same problem I had.

Its very simple i was searching for Hibernate types and I found this sentence:

- If the type you have is no Basic Hibernate Type and you only want to save it in 1 Column dont write in the Hibernate XML a type and let hibernate decide which typ to use.

If you make your property like normal with name column and type. Hibernate will try if the type is possible for yoru input in my case a int Array. And Hibernate will answer you that the type is unknown. If you set the type to byte[] hibernate will answer you : Do not know to convert int array to byte array.

The Solution is simple just do not set type. Write the property like this:

```
<property name="route" column="route"/>
```

Hibernate will now look up which type you will need and set it for you. And everything works fine, and like you want to do it. On the internet you will find alot of resources for array, set and list. All this things will provide a new Tabel special for you array.

If you want to do this go check the internet its full with, helpfull examples. If you just want to save Objects and Hibernate dont know the type just dont set type in your XML.